# dynamic minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, insert, minimum-spanning-tree

I want to make a dynamic minimum spanning tree. I have an existing MS tree over n vertices and I add one more vertex and edges to all the existing vertices from this new vertex. How can I update the MST for the new graph efficiently? O(n) would be optimal. Can I also make delete vertex operation efficient?

Comment: Related --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679472/updating-a-minimum-spanning-tree-when-a-new-edge-is-inserted

Comment: Here I am increasing the size of the tree and introducing n new edges, it might be the case that every edge gets replaced and still time taken should be O(n).

Comment: When you add a vertex, do you always add edges from the new vertex to *all* the existing vertices ? If so, the new MST is just NEW-VERTEX + MST...

Comment: yes, to all the existing vertices

Comment: So just take the NEW_VERTEX and link it to the MST root. Jobs done. (if I'm not missing something)

Comment: it is a weighted graph. That is a point of a MST - Minimum total weight.

Comment: Oh yes, that's the missing point. Sorry I forgot the "minimum" meaning (I was thinking to the minimum number of "hops") ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9160/discussion-between-anirudh-and-digemall)

Answer (score 2):

`O(n log n)` using Kruskal's algorithm. The key idea is any edges not used in the original MST will not be used in the new MST either. So just sort the `n` new edges `O(n log n)`, merge this sorted list with the list of edges of the old MST (which you kept in sorted order, right?) `O(n)`, then run Kruskal's algorithm anew on the resulting sorted list of edges `O(n)-ish`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using locality sensitive ordering. Please refer to the [this](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/10114/pdf/LIPIcs-ITCS-2019-21.pdf) paper. They discuss on the cost of forming a dynamic minimum spanning tree and that it gives a (1+epsilon) approximation over the most optimal solution.